# Laravel 404 not found when passing parameter with route()

Tags: laravel

Hello I have instructors table, and every instructor have name column and I have a page to show events and every event has instructor name and I need to go to the instructor profile page when clicking on the instructor name in the events page so I made this

```
<a href="{{ route('instructor.profile', ['name' => $event->instructor]) }}" class="a-reset">
    <h5 class="color-primary fw-bold">{{ $event->instructor }}</h5>
</a>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/instructor/{name}', 'App\Http\Controllers\InstructorController@profile')->name('instructor.profile');
```

InstructorController

```
public function profile($name) {
    $instructor = Instructor::where('name', '=', $name)->first();

    return view('instructor-profile', compact('instructor'));
}
```

But it gives me 404 Not Found error page

Comment: looks good, but surely the route does not exists, or there is some redirection.  I suggest you to check the generated link (probably the instructor name is empty) and check the routes with "artisan route:list"

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure it returns value **$event->instructor**
2. Make sure the address is correct i**nstructor-profile**
3. by this command **rtisan route:list** open route list, make sure it is there **/instructor/{name}** route.
4. if everything is correct run this command

php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:cache